# How to turn off materialize css containers when on mobile?

Tags: materialize

The container class is used to restrict content to 70% of screen width.  Works wonderfully for our app on medium and larger containers.

Unfortunately, we then want 100% spacing on small.  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my code I just do something like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: the size you need)
  .container
    width: 98%
```

I just call this after importing the materializecss sass and override the default behavior

Here is the code they use and which you have to override: [link](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/components/_grid.scss)